# unresolved external symbol "private: static int Math::result"

Tags: c++, static

this is my class definition:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Math
{
private:
    static int result;

public:
    static int add( int a , int b)
    {
        result = a + b ;
        return result;
    };
};
```

---

this is the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Amin.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Math::add(2,3);
}
```

and i got these errors in visual studio:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int Math::result" 
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

best regards

Comment: This has been asked and answered many, many times. Search first, please.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just add

```
int Math::result;
```

in your `cpp` file.

`Math::result` is declared as a `static` data variable in the definition of `Math` and should be defined somewhere. This can be the `cpp` file containing `main()` or any other to be found by the linker. You need not and should not repeat the keyword `static` at the definition.

By the way, you should avoid `using namespace std;` (or any other namespace) in a header file.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a static variable in your `Math` class. You need to provide a definition for it. To do this you can add:

```
int Math::result;
```

to your .cpp file

Comment: i have two cpp file, which one should i put it and where should i put it in them?

Comment: Either, you just need to put it in one, and no more than one.